# How get all links from a web page and its sub pages in Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I wrote a program to get all the links from a webpage and then get all the links from that sub page.

**For example:** I have page [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and found five other links: [example.com/home](http://example.com/home), [example.com/contact](http://example.com/contact), etc. I should go to these links and check again for links on that webpage.

**How should I implement this?**

Also, I need a list of already visited pages and blocked pages (Link to Facebook, for example, because then I think it will be in the infinite loop).

Here is my code so far (Which only gives me the links from one webpage and not its subpages):

```
 try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.example.com/").get();
        Elements elements = doc.select("a");
        for(Element element : elements){
            System.out.println(element.absUrl("href"));
            list.add(element.absUrl("href"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You need to write with more clarity. Your English is poor and you don't really describe what you are trying to do very well.  For example, what does "blocked" mean?

Comment: when I get links from the home page and then I will come to each of them and again I will take all the links. etc and more..
blocket - when it detects a link from another site(facebook/com...etc) and how come there and so was not looking for because it is a different page and can go to infinity loop..

1. i get links from main site.
2. go to each of them and again get all links from this site
3.again step 2...and again 2
stop when i got all links from all sites from this domain

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion. Put your code in a method, for example

```
void getLinks(String url, Set<String> urls) {

    if (urls.contains(url)) {
        return;
    }
    urls.add(url);

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements elements = doc.select("a");
        for(Element element : elements){
            System.out.println(element.absUrl("href"));
            getLinks(element.absUrl("href"), urls);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then you can start the execution like this:

```
Set<String> links = new HashSet<>();
getLinks("https://www.example.com/", links);
```

Comment: Just ran into this via Google - when running this, my program simply terminated. I discovered it was due to this line: `if(url.contains(url))`. The URL that I passed in always contains itself, so it always returns immediately.

Comment: @Jake Typo! Fixed now

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I thought that was what you meant, but it's always hard to tell when looking at someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

After adding all the links to your list of links

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.example.com/").get();
    Elements elements = doc.select("a");
    for(Element element : elements){
        System.out.println(element.absUrl("href"));
        list.add(element.absUrl("href")); //<-------HERE*****
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can then simply connect to each one of those in the same way that you connected to the first one, using

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    doc = Jsoup.connect(list.get(i)).get();
    //do whatever you want
}
```

If you don't want a particular link, I'd recommend putting the undesired links in a hashmap, and checking against them before adding them to your list(s) of links to other pages.

Comment: Just a note because nobody else has left a comment on your post. You bring up using a HashMap for placing undesired links and checking against them, if you use a HashSet, this check is never actually necessary.